# Hotmail duplicate address

Tags: outlook.com

I have a Gmail account. Let's call it 1234@gmail.com for example's sake. I've recently created the very same address on Hotmail. It's exactly the same as Gmail address - 1234@gmail.com

But whenever I try to send an email to this address - only Gmail version receives it. Why does it work like that? Addresses are exactly the same but only Gmail version receives mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what you've created is a login, not an email address. Messages to a Gmail address will only go to Gmail servers. You need to set up email forwarding from Gmail to Outlook.com.